# How $U_{q}(\mathfrak{sl}_{2})$ becomes the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{sl}_{2})$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_{2}$

Tags: lie-algebras, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

[image]

My question is how $U_{q}(\mathfrak{sl}_{2})$ becomes the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{sl}_{2})$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_{2}$ if we set $t=q^h$ and $q$ tends to 1.

Comment: where is the excerpt from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is not meant to be computed with directly substituting $q=1$. It is indeterminate.

There are various approaches for doing this computation: Formally, the general idea is to expand $t=q^h$ as a power series in $h$ and then to keep the lowest order terms (in $h$). Then you will get as the $q\to 1$ limit, your last relations (i.e. the relations of the classical enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$). (I think that this is more or less similar to the original approach of Drinfeld). 
For more details you can see [A Quantum Groups Primer](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521010412), LMS, Lecture Note Series (No. 292), 2002 by Shahn Majid, ch.7, p. 42-43.

Fo another approach, based on an algebra $U^{'}_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ isomorphic to $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ for $q\neq 1$, which is however defined also for $q=1$,  you can see at C. Kassel's book on [Quantum groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387943706), ch. $VI$, sect. $2$, p. 125-126 (Prop. 2.1, 2.2). Alternatively, see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/126461/85967) question in MO. This is (imo) more conceptual and less computational, but I'm afraid it fits less to the way you have posed your question.